# Has European Patent Office granted Monsanto a patent on natural broccoli seeds and florets?

Tags: gmo, patents

[An article on Natural News](http://www.naturalnews.com/041014_Monsanto_seed_patents_GMOs.html) claims that

> EPO granted Monsanto a patent on conventionally-bred broccoli, which includes not only broccoli seeds but also the "severed broccoli head" and the "plurality of broccoli plants ... grown in a field of broccoli" - in other words, broccoli in all of its natural forms.

Is this accurate - has such a wide patent on broccoli (e.g. including forms of natural broccoli not developed by Monstanto) been granted, and is it accurate to summarize it as a patent on broccoli "in all of its natural forms"?

Comment: The patent the article is referring to might be this one: https://data.epo.org/publication-server/pdf-document?PN=EP1597965+EP+1597965&iDocId=7994889&iepatch=.pdf

Comment: [Patent EP 1597965 is cited @no-patents-on-seeds.org](http://www.no-patents-on-seeds.org/en/information/news/monsanto-granted-patent-severed-broccoli) I tried a search on that # and came up empty but i may not totally understand the search tool.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using the [EPO patent search](https://register.epo.org/regviewer), it is relatively easy to reject that such a patent has been granted.

EPO has not granted *any* patents directly to Montsano containing the word "broccoli" (search term: "Brocolli ia=Monsanto").

The patent you are linking to in your comment [EP 1 597 965 B1](https://data.epo.org/publication-server/pdf-document?PN=EP1597965%20EP%201597965&iDocId=7994889&iepatch=.pdf) is the only patent granted by the EPO containing the word "broccoli". The patent proprietor "Seminis Vegetable Seeds, Inc." is owned by Monsanto, so even if it was not granted to Monsanto, it is indeed owned by Monsanto.

The patent does however not cover conventionally bred broccoli, but a modified variety, basically with a longer stalk with less leaves than conventional varieties, making it easier to mechanically harvest the crop.

A patent grant is not confirmation of the patent's validity. Patent offices do examine the patent application, but it is not possible for a patent office to perform a complete search for prior art. I believe that conventionally bred broccoli would be found to be prior art, making a granted patent invalid IMHO.

Comment: It is difficult to trust empty patent searches as proof of absense - e.g. your third paragraph demonstrates that the search term in your second paragraph is insufficient: searching for "Monsanto" isn't enough.

Comment: In fact, I get 23 hits when I search for broccoli: https://register.epo.org/smartSearch?searchMode=smart&query=broccoli

Comment: and no, the prior existence of broccoli does not indicate prior art, as the patent is for a specific application of a specific mutation, not a blanket patent on growing broccoli.

Comment: @Oddthinking: The other 22 patents are not yet granted but still in the application and examination process.

Comment: @jwenting: I was not saying that the patent I linked to is void because of prior art. The article in Natural News claims that "EPO granted Monsanto a patent on conventionally-bred broccoli", which seem to be false. But if such a patent had been granted, it would IMHO been void because of obvious prior art.

Comment: @Tor-Einar: Ahh. Okay. Sorry.

Comment: @Sancho: A reference for the cultivation of conventional broccoli before April 2005 (the filing date of the patent)?

Comment: @Sancho: I still don't understand what you want to be verified with a reference. As I asked: Do you want a reference for the cultivation of conventional broccoli before April 2005 (A)? Do you want a reference to the meaning of "prior art" and if so, what kind of reference (B)? A link to a dictionary? Or do you want a reference to a legal text, confirming that a patent cannot be granted on prior art (C)? It is of course not possible or easy to find a reference to the entire conclusion "if A, then B and because of C, the patent is invalid", but that is common logic.

Comment: The EPO, unlike the US Patent Office, does examine patents for validity. If common broccoli were prior art, this would have been detected.

Comment: @Sancho: I honestly do not agree. Neither the cultivation of broccoli, the meaning of prior art (or state of the art, as it is called in the European Patent Convention), nor the requirement for novelty in patent applications are my opinions.

Comment: @DJClaywort: No, it only *should* have been detected. How would it be practically possible for a patent office to conduct a complete search in the worldwide knowledge to conclude that prior art does not exists, which would invalidate a patent application?